# Как вызвать класс AsyncTask из Activity?

Tags: java, android

В методе

```
public class MainActivity { ... }
```

я создал класс:

```
class checkAuth extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

как мне его вызвать в методе?

```
protected void onCreate { ... }
```

Пробовал (не действует):

```
checkAuth ();
```

Comment: Это public class MainActivity { ... } разве объявление метода?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я не совсем понимаю. Я web разработчик. А тут такая задача подвернулась.

Comment: Из вашего описания не ясно где, как и что вы создали, и как это созданное собираетесь вызывать.

Comment: Вы практикуете какое то программирование наугад, да?  [Почитать](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php), как это делается правильно что то мешает .. Что, можно как то вообще писать программы и не понимать, что ты пишешь - методом тыка, и потом еще ожидать, что оно будет "действовать"

Comment: @pavlofff именно там я это и читал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Понятия «вызвать класс» не существует. Можно создать экземпляр данного класса с помощью `new checkAuth()` (либо передав нужные параметры в конструктор). В дальнейшем можно вызывать методы этого экземпляра. `extends AsyncTask` намекает, что вам надо вызвать метод `execute()`:

```
new checkAuth().execute();
```

Comment: Можно "вызвать" статический класс, так что понятие все же существует :)

Comment: @pavlofff, статический класс - это обычный класс объявленный внутри другого. С точки зрения JVM ничем не отличается от обычного класса. Вы имеете в виду "вызвать статический *метод* класса"? Но опять же это вызов метода.

Comment: Не обязательно статический класс - внутренний класс. Статический класс - класс, который может использоваться без создания экземпляра класса и быть вполне самостоятельным, как `Math` в Java API. Да, чтобы получить какие то действия от такого класса, нужно вызывать его статические методы, но экземпляр не требуется,  `Math.cos(1);` В андроид статические классы - активити - их экземпляры не создаются и они вполне себе "вызываются" формально. Ясно, что без вызова методов любого класса никаких действий не произойдет, я к тому, что создание экземпляра - не обязательное условие использования класса.

Comment: @pavlofff, такой класс не называется статическим, не путайте понятия. Его можно назвать утилитным, например. Статические методы могут быть и в классе, который предполагается инстанциировать. И использование статических методов всё же не называется «вызовом класса», а вызовом метода. Ну и я не говорил, что нельзя вызвать методы без создания экземпляра, просто этот сценарий не относится к сути данного вопроса.